# Schrodinger's Bootmngr

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, bootmgr

A few days ago my laptop started BSOD'ing on every boot, whilst it was loading the windows kernel. After some attempts to fix it, I finally decided that it might be simpler to start with a fresh install.

I did have linux on the same ssd as windows, but found myself never using it. I somehow cacked up the removal of grub, and now there's a windows bootloader/bootmngr but it's not being seen after post. grub's definitely gone, and there's definitely a bootloader -somewhere-...

If I boot from a rescue usb stick I can select the windows partition and then it loads the bootmngr where I select my windows installation and boot (there is a second physical disk with an old install of windows which I use as a data disk but is no longer a disk I boot from, which yes, I should really fix too).

so, although by itself when the computer boots it reports "bootmgr is missing", it's actually possible to boot into the new windows install and use it.

under computer management it reports the new install as bootable:

[image]

and visual bcd editor

[image]

There's a working install of windows on disk 0. I want to get the bootloader into the right place so that it loads windows. how do I do this? I've tried repairing it by booting from a windows usb stick, I've tried all the various advice that's easily searchable, and I'm feeling slightly at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple commands would make disk 0 (SSD) bootable.

Disk has already an active partition.

1. `bcdboot Z:\windows /s Z:` where Z: is drive letter of SSD

just in case boot records can be updated

2. `bootsect /nt60 Z: /mbr` where Z: is again your SSD drive

You can use bootsect.exe from Visual BCD installation directory, from Windows Recovery or Windows PE.

Automatic Repair of [Dual-boot Repair tool](http://www.boyans.net) would not function in this case as your System Reserved partition as seen on image is on another disk ("RECOVERY" partition on disk 1).